# Best practices to get a new row id from database

Tags: database, web-applications, relational-database

hi i am creating a project where i am actually having **3 related tables** which are **connected to one table** like below

**table 1**

```
id
name
```

**table 2**

```
id
tb1_id
random_thing
```

**table 3**

```
id
tb1_id
random_thing
```

i can not basically go with an option where i can **create a row in table1 first and then tb2,tb3** . client wants **everything to be done on single button** . so i am creating a **new blank row whenever the page is called** and getting the **new tb1_id and then linking everything and go with single button** but the problem is i can delete unused rows like 2-3 days later but **thats ridiculous** so is there any other **best practices to get over situations such as this?**

**Edit**

**Explanation with an example will be really helpful , i am good to go with any database or any language just example has to be good so i can understand how its done.** sorry but i am one of those guys who hates theory and love practicals :d

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use explicit foreign key relationships and transactions.

So, the basic idea is:

1. Begin a transaction.
2. Insert a row in table 1 with the name.
3. Get the id of the newly created row, ideally using a `returning` or `output` clause (depending on the database).
4. Insert a row in table 2.
5. Insert a row in table 3.
6. Commit the transaction.

When using transactions, just be careful to rollback the transaction if it does not complete for any reason.

As for deleting rows, you can have "cascading delete" options on the foreign key definitions, so if the parent row is deleted then the related rows are also deleted.

Some databases (notably Postgres) offer some functionality where you can put all this into a single statement using CTEs that modify the data.  The idea is still the same, just easier to code.

I should note that there are perfectly reasonable alternatives.  For instance, you could create a view on the "data" columns of the three tables and create insert/update/delete triggers on the view.  Personally, I find that hiding this functionality in triggers makes it more difficult to understand and maintain.  I think that is a personal opinion and this is also a reasonable approach.

Comment: hi , thanks for reply i am good to go with any database can you show me an example of it with any database (language wont matter if the tutorial is good) , and i am not using the trending nosql etc but still knowledge is sacred :) so that will do too.

Comment: @noobProgrammer . . . For whatever database you are using, look up the documentation on transactions.  That is usually a good place to start.

Comment: i thought on SO i can get some answers not a suggesion to read documentations. seriously i respect you for giving me answer i just want an example , if you ever done it you have to have a sample code for it thats what i think or you are just writing voices in your head without being sure of if it works or not